# ReactJS best practice with complex data structures

Tags: javascript, oop, reactjs

I am integrating React into an existing app. This app is data intensive and the data structure is pretty complicated which makes it a bit hard for me to adapt the React patterns, especially statelessness and composition.

Given data like this:

```js
component: {
  options: [optionA, optionB, optionC]
}

options: {
  optionA : {
    name: 'FOO',
    choices: [choiceA, choiceB, choiceC]
  },
  optionB : {
    name: 'BAR',
    choices: [choiceD, choiceE]
  },
  ...
}

choices: {
  choiceA : {
    type: 'typeA',
    choices: [choiceA, choiceB, choiceC],
    name: 'abb'
  },
  choiceB : {
    type: 'typeB',
    name: 'abc'
  },
  ...
}
```

Since this data is linked by ids I have two possibilities:

1. Retrieve children data in parent component and pass it to the children.
2. Pass the ID and children retrieves it's own data.

One implies dynamically retrieving a components props and the other implies having a "god" parent which has all the necessary data for it's children, which one is the better approach?

My other question is if the component that takes a Choice as its props should display differently depending on the type of it's Choice, is the better approach to make a wrapper component like this? :

```js
class Choice extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  
  render(){
    switch(props.choice.type){
       case "typeA":
         return (<TypeAComponent />);
       case "typeB":
         return (<TypeBComponent />);
       default:
          return (..);
    }
  }
}
```

Or is there a cleaner alternative (I'm a bit allergic to switch cases)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ad your first question:**

I would opt for the first solution i.e. retrieving the data in the parent. This will make move to some kind of state management (`redux`) if you choose so much easier (it will be handled in one place only).

**Ad your second question:**

You can get rid of the switch using a dictionary:

```
const choiceRenderers = {
    "typeA": () => <TypeAComponent />,
    "typeB": () => <TypeBComponent />,
    // etc.
};

class Choice extends Component {
    render() {
        const renderer = choiceRenderers[this.props.choice.type];
        return renderer
            ? renderer()
            : <DefaultChoice />;
    }
}
```

The potential advantage is that this choice—component mapping could be shared across multiple components without replicating it, you can just store it in a module and import it when needed.

Comment: Thanks that confirms what I was thinking!
About moving to Redux, do you think it's adaptable with deeply linked data structures?

Comment: According to redux's creator, [Dan Abramov](http://stackoverflow.com/users/458193/dan-abramov), it works better with shallow state trees. For more info, I cannot recommend his [egghead course](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-normalizing-the-state-shape) enough, it is a great resource for learning all about it